# Is there an equivalent of graphstream (Java) in HTML5 (canvas + JavaScript)

Tags: java, javascript, html, canvas, graph

[GraphStream](http://www.graphstream-project.org/) is a dynamic graph library written in Java that provides Java developers a way to easily represent dynamic graphs in memory, on screen or in files. [Video demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XX5rRF6uxow&list=UUXAWLKCPQfyBuINOpYp37Cw&feature=plcp).

GraphStream provides a framework to handle the evolution of graphs, that is the changes on values stored on edges and nodes of a graph during time, but also the "topology" changes of the graph, that is the addition, removal and modification of nodes and edges during time.

Is there an equivalent of GraphStream in HTML5 (element canvas with JavaScript) with this kind of algoritmes :

- Welsh-Powell
- Betweenness Centrality
- Random walks on graphs
- Several often used algorithms on graphs
- Base for spanning-tree algorithm
- BellmanFord
- Kruskal, spanning-tree algorithm
- Prim, spanning-tree algorithm
- Centroid
- Eccentricity
- All Pair Shortest Path
- Dijkstra
- Connected Components
- etc.

Comment: Did you have a look at d3.js? http://mbostock.github.com/d3/

Comment: @Mic This library does cover my needs in part. However, It lacks partly due to the algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know about other tools but as a GraphStream dev I can tell about perspectives of the project.

We do not plan to rewrite the all project in JS, however we are working on a Web based viewer.  The idea would be to keep the graph/algorithmic part on the server side, and to focus on the visualization on the client side.

Technologies on the server side would lead to a connection between GraphStream and a Web server. On the client side investigated techs for now are:

- HTML5 canvas drawing for the visualization;
- WebSocket communication channels for the client/server communication.